# Remove user from all non AD groups

Tags: powershell

I've been in the process of creating a script to terminate a user when they leave the company. I having a hard time figuring out how to remove all the groups from a user. For the AD groups I use`Get-Aduser -Identity $varUserName -Properties Memberof | ForEach-Object { $_.Memberof | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $varUserName -Confirm:$false}` this works perfect. The issue I'm having is with O365/Entra/Exchange Online groups. I'm currently using:

```
    $Groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $varEmail -All $true | Where-Object {$_.IsSystem -like ""}
foreach($group in $Groups) {
    try {
        $varAzureADGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $group.ObjectID | Where-Object {$_.DirSyncEnabled -ne "True"} | select displayname, mailenabled,securityenabled,objectid
        $AzureADMSGroup = Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id $group.objectid 
        if($group.DirSyncEnabled -ne "True") {
            Write-Host "Removing" $Group.DisplayName "Group"
            if(($varAzureADGroup.SecurityEnable) -and ($varAzureADGroup.MailEnabled -eq $null)){
                # Removes Azure AD Groups
                Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectID -MemberId $varName
                Write-Host $Group.DisplayName "has been removed."
            }
            if(($varAzureADGroup.MailEnabled) -and ($varAzureADGroup.SecurityEnable -eq $null)){
                # Removes Exchanges Groups
                Remove-DistributionGroupMember -identity $group.ObjectId -member $varEmail -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -Confirm:$false
                Write-Host $Group.DisplayName "has been removed."
            }
            if(($varAzureADGroup.MailEnabled) -and ($varAzureADGroup.SecurityEnable)){
                # Removes Microsoft 365 Groups
                Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $group.DisplayName -Links $varEmail -LinkType members -Confirm:$false
                Write-Host $Group.DisplayName "has been removed."
            }
        }
    } 
    Catch {
        Write-Host $Group.DisplayName "was not removed." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

This will get most the groups except for a GroupMailbox type.

How do I determine which command to use on which group? I'm only asking about any non-AD groups.

Feel free to rewrite the code if the is a better way to do this.

Comment: Why don’t you just disable the account? You never know when an employee might come back…